# break function does not work when the correct password and username are entered from the file

Tags: python

Break function does not work when I enter the correct username and password from the file. The words 'access to something special' print infinitely. How do I fix this? I want the program to start again if the user enters the password/username wrong.

```
content2=input('Username:')
content=input('Password:')

while True:
    file=open('username1.txt','r')
    data1 =file.read()
    file.close()

    file1=open('password1.txt','r')
    data2 =file1.read()
    file1.close()

    data1 = data1.split("\n")
    data2 = data2.split("\n")

    for i in range(len(data1)):
        if data1[i] == content2 and data2[i] == content:
            print('You have access to something special.')
            break
        else:
            print('Access denied.')
```

Comment: Your `break` will jump you out of the `for` loop only. Not the `while` loop.

Comment: You `break` from `for` loop but you remain in `while true` loop.

Comment: Why do you need the `while True:` loop at all?

Comment: So if the user enters the wrong username/password it will restart

Comment: But the user name and password prompt is outside of the `while` loop. Even if you did have a way to restart it, those two lines before the `while True` wouldn't run again. (And it's `continue` that runs a loop again; `break` stops the loop entirely.)

Comment: @ArthurTacca The OP had quite a bit wrong with the code, I wrote something that works as they want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your most recent edit, I see what you really want...

Note that I have removed the second `break` here, as when `looping` through the `usernames`, if the entered `username` doesn't match, we don't want to `deny` straight away, we want to keep checking...

```
file = open('username1.txt','r')
usernames = file.read().split("\n")
file.close()

file = open('password1.txt','r')
passwords = file.read().split("\n")
file.close()

passed = False

while not passed:
    username = input('Username:')
    password = input('Password:')
    for i in range(len(usernames)):
        if usernames[i] == username and passwords[i] == password:
            print('You have access to something special.')
            passed = True
            break
    else:
        print('Access denied. Try again')
```

Comment: infinitely prints access denied

Comment: @TheCompStudentAJ Sorry I missed a couple of things because I hadn't properly tested it. I have now made the files and checked with some different cases and it seems to be working well! **:)** please up-vote and accept if it works for you too! Sorry for the mistakes before

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag to get out of the while:

```
with open('username1.txt') as infile:
    data1 = infile.read().split('\n')

with open('password1.txt') as infile:
    data2 = infile.read().split('\n')

flag = True
while flag:
    content2 = input('Username:')
    content = input('Password:')

    for i in range(len(data1)):
        if data1[i] == content2 and data2[i] == content:
            print('You have access to something special.')
            flag = False
            break
        else:
            print('Access denied.')
```

Comment: this infinitely loops access denied

Comment: As other people have mentioned, you don't need the while loop, it will loop infinitely regardless of the outcome of the for loop. I was merely giving a method of exiting the while. You could also add the flag to the access denied portion if you need the while.